# How to reconnect wire in this solar panel connector (automotive)

Tags: connector

[image]

I need to reinsert this wire into the connector but I don't see any way to get the old wire out and insert a new wire or fasten it. Is anyone familiar with this connector?

Comment: The wires are held in the connector by setscrews at right-angles to the wire and pin - there is a hole for one screw visible in your picture.  If the wire is broken off inside the connector, it will be very difficult.  You may be able to remove the screw, and push the wire out using a sharp object through the screw hole.

Comment: Really? Looks moulded. No chance for a simple repair. Buy a pigtail of the same connector and splice the cables.